# Remote desktop certificate error - how to connect anyways?

Tags: ssl-certificate, remote-desktop

I have a remote server that I can only access through RDP.  It uses a proper SSL certificate from godaddy for RDP, not a self signed one.  The server is 2008R2, and I believe is set to the default of requiring network level authentication.  Unfortunately, I do not have any lights out management features or IPKVM on this server.

Due to heartbleed, I revoked all my certificates and reissued them.  Unfortunately, I clearly missed setting RDP up for this new certificate.  Now I get "This certificate has been revoked and is not safe to use", and "You may not proceed due to the severity of the certificate errors".

I know the certificate is revoked.  That's why I'm trying to get in to fix it!  But I can't replace the certificate until I can remote in.  And I can't remote in until I replace the certificate.

Is my only option to drive there and login from the console, or is there a way to temporarily ignore the certificate error?

[image]

Comment: Use freerdp from a Linux box to connect?

Comment: Or an XP, for that purpose. It doesn't check the certificate's revocation either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NathanC's suggestion of using mmc from another computer worked perfectly.

Another option which works if you can't access it that way is using program which doesn't validate the certificate.  Apparently Microsoft's RD Client for android is one such program.

Answer (score 8):

Use with caution (as per Microsoft):
There is a registry entry you can enter so this will go away:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE - Software – Microsoft – Terminal Server Client
Add a new DWORD called AuthenticationLevelOverride and set its value to 0.

[image: AuthenticationLevelOverride]

You can also push this out via GPO:
Open Group Policy Management and create or edit a Group Policy Object
Under computer configuration - Preferences - Windows Settings - Registry
Right click and create a new registry item:

```
Action: Create
Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
Key Path: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client
Value name: AuthenticationLevelOverride
Value Type: REG_DWORD
Value data: 00000000
Hexadecimal
```

[image: Reg]

Comment: This works correctly for Win Server 2012 at least.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `mmc` to accomplish what you need since the snap-in works on remote computers. See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731617.aspx. The caveat to this is that you need another Windows Server computer handy to use this snap-in, and working over the network is questionable if the firewall blocks a lot of things.

Comment: That worked.  I am lucky enough to have another server with a private unfirewalled connection between the two.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to connect with the server's FQDN rather than just the hostname. That way the computer name matched the certificate.

This requirement seems to have developed with one of the recent updates.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, NLA is the opposite of the server authentication. NLA is User authentication of the *connecting* user. See [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732713.aspx)

Server authentication is handled by the client.
In RDP, go to `Advanced` and change `Server authentication` to `"Warn me"`

[image]

Comment: I have tried "Warn me" and "Connect and don't warn me".  Neither option allows me to proceed, I get the error shown in the screenshot.

Comment: OK.. interesting!